# Iterating through permutations that fit a specific key

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, python-itertools

Imagine some list

```
L = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(11,12,13)]
```

I want to iterate through all permutations of this list that fit an arbitrary length key such as `(2,2,3,3,3)`.

So in this case, all permutations where the length of the elements fits that key.

```
[(7,8),(9,10),(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(11,12,13)]

[(9,10),(7,8),(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(11,12,13)]

[(7,8),(9,10),(4,5,6),(1,2,3),(11,12,13)]
```

etc.

Right now I am just iterating through *all* permutations and only taking the ones that fit the key, but this goes through a lot of wasted time and permutations. I'd much rather generate what I need directly but I don't know how to do it at all, despite looking into itertools more deeply.

Comment: Don't worry about having to do it directly. `permutations` returns an iterator, so you can just check as you go.

Comment: For large lists, doing it directly is a massive time saver. It wastes way too much time going through needless permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the permutations of the tuples of different lengths spearately and combine them:

```
from itertools import chain, permutations, product
tuples_by_length = {}
for t in L:
    tuples_by_length.setdefault(len(t), []).append(t)
for x, y in product(permutations(tuples_by_length[2]),
                    permutations(tuples_by_length[3])):
    print list(chain(x, y))
```

Output:

```
[(7, 8), (9, 10), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (11, 12, 13)]
[(7, 8), (9, 10), (1, 2, 3), (11, 12, 13), (4, 5, 6)]
[(7, 8), (9, 10), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (11, 12, 13)]
[(7, 8), (9, 10), (4, 5, 6), (11, 12, 13), (1, 2, 3)]
[(7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12, 13), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
[(7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12, 13), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3)]
[(9, 10), (7, 8), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (11, 12, 13)]
[(9, 10), (7, 8), (1, 2, 3), (11, 12, 13), (4, 5, 6)]
[(9, 10), (7, 8), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (11, 12, 13)]
[(9, 10), (7, 8), (4, 5, 6), (11, 12, 13), (1, 2, 3)]
[(9, 10), (7, 8), (11, 12, 13), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
[(9, 10), (7, 8), (11, 12, 13), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3)]
```

This approach can be generalised to arbitrary length keys:

```
def permutations_with_length_key(lst, length_key):
    tuples_by_length = {}
    for t in L:
        tuples_by_length.setdefault(len(t), []).append(t)
    positions = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(tuples_by_length.iterkeys())}
    for x in product(*[permutations(v) for v in tuples_by_length.itervalues()]):
        x = map(iter, x)
        yield [next(x[positions[y]]) for y in length_key]
```

Comment: I don't believe this works by a specific key -- it just does permutations of length two followed by those of length three. What if I needed something that fit key (2,2,1,3,3,2,4), etc?

Comment: @DoubleBass: You didn't ask for this to work for arbitrary length keys.  You only asked for `[2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`.  I've updated my answer.  Please update your question as well.